# How to create .json file and write into that file with data using PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have form for image upload. After uploading the image with title i store the image in a directory. Instead storing the image **name** & **title** into database table i want to store that information into a `.json` file *as same as a record goes to a table of database*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can take the benefit of `File Storage` functions in `Laravel`

use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

and then

```
 $data = [
    "name" => $image_name,
    "title" => $image_title
]

    Storage::disk('public')->put('images.json', json_encode($data));
```

and this file will be save in `public` folder

References:

[Laravel -> File System](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-local-driver)